# Nginx reverse proxy for Angular apps

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have created a reverse proxy using Nginx which redirects in various applications (ASP.NET API's and Angular app's).

Reverse proxy nginx.conf (the most important settings):

```
...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;

    location /projects/sample-app1/api {
        proxy_pass http://sample-app1-api:80;
    }

    location /projects/sample-app1 {
        # Angular app
        proxy_pass http://sample-app1:80;
    }

    location /projects/sample-app2 {
        # Angular app 
        proxy_pass http://sample-app2:80;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://random-api:80;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://personal-app:80;
    }
}
```

All API's are available and work properly because their path indicated by the location parameter is the same as in the controllers. An Angular application that runs on the url "/" also works, but the problem is with "sample-app1" and "sample-app2". When I type the url to go to these applications, I get an error similar to:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < main.d6f56a1….bundle.js:1
```

My suspicion is that the URL leading to the application contains additional elements (/projects/sample-app1) and its default index path is simply "/". So I would have to rewrite to remove the redundant part of the URL, but how to do it? My attempts so far have not been successful and I have tried different ways from other threads on StackOverflow and Github.

Angular App nginx.conf:

```
events{}
http {
   include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

   server {
       listen 80;
       server_name localhost;
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
       index index.html;

       location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
       }
   }
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the solution is the response of the user: [Esmaeil Mazahery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1761928/esmaeil-mazahery), but a few more steps must be taken.

First, I changed the Angular application Dockerfile (passed additional build parameters like: base-href and deploy-url)

```
RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --base-href /projects/sample-app1/ --deploy-url /projects/sample-app1/
```

Then, I changed the reverse proxy nginx.conf configuration from

```
location /projects/sample-app1 {
    # Angular app
    proxy_pass http://sample-app1:80;
}
```

to:

```
location /projects/sample-app1 {
    # Angular app
    proxy_pass http://sample-app1:80/;
}
```

Redirection did not work properly without a slash at the end.

The order in which nginx redirects are matched is also important. Therefore, before the addresses: `/projects/sample-app1` and `/projects/sample-app2` I put the symbol `^~`, which causes the given locations to be taken first. This nginx localization simulation tool also proved very useful: [Nginx location match tester](https://nginx.viraptor.info)

Comment: Excellent, I had exactly that issue, I'll take note of that for further reference, :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the path of your subfolder when launching a build :

```
ng build --base-href=/subfolder/
```

in debugging mode you can add extra parameters

```
ng serve -o --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check --base-href=/subfolder/
```

nginx config

```
location /subfolder {
        proxy_pass http://app:80/subfolder;
}
```

Comment: So from what I understand, I should set ng build --base-href = / projects / sample-app1 / for "sample-app1" to make everything work properly? Correct my words if I'm wrong.

Comment: yes if is not some part of path in angular routing you must set all path you wish deploy app

Comment: Still not working, maybe should I make some changes to the nginx.conf of an Angular application?

Comment: add path to nginx proxy_pass